# Raspberry Pi vs BeagleBone torrentbox

Tags: raspberry-pi, beaglebone-black

I'm planning to make an always on torrentbox, I get my internet from a 4g usb dongle modem, but I've very limited experience with such boards. From what I read on the internet, it seems BeagleBone is little bit more powerful and has an easier time setting up than Rpi, but it is slightly more expensive and I'm on a shoestring budget. Which board would better suited for my kind of project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi will do everything you need, and I can't imagine the BeagleBone being any simpler to set up. All you do is flash an SD card (with the very simple Win32DiskImager in Windows, for example), plug it in and SSH to it. Or use the HDMI port with a keyboard if you prefer.

Are you plugging the 4G dongle directly to it? If not, be aware that the Ethernet port is limited to less than 2MB/s due to the very weak power regulators on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I also found that there are a lot more guides for rpi, since it's very popular; from that, and from what you've said I'll be going for a rpi. Thanks!